# Qual é a finalidade e como usar Broadcasting no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, websocket

A versão 5.3 do Laravel está com umas novidades, como o [Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting), por exemplo.

Eu li a documentação, mas não consegui entender muito bem a respeito do tema.

Eu vi que  tem alguma relação (se direta ou indireta, não sei) com os Websockets. Vi também que, na pasta `routes`, existe um arquivo chamado `channels.php`, onde há um código de exemplo:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

Eu queria saber mais profundamente:

- Do que se trata esse broadcasting no Laravel?
- Em que situações eu posso usá-lo, por exemplo?
- Qual é a relação entre o Broadcasting do Laravel e Websockets?

<sub>A pergunta tem o intuito de ter o conteúdo na lingua portuguesa, devido não ter achado nada na internet no nosso idioma</sub>

Comment: Por coincidência, estou trabalhando nisso hoje ***=)*** Se sobrar uns minutos, eu tento responder algo.

Comment: Vai ser sensacional @LINQ :)

Answer (score 1):

A finalidade é trabalhar com eventos em tempo Real ex:
tem 2 páginas abertas uma que lista os usuários e outra que adiciona, Ao adicionar um novo, a página que lista automaticamente recebe o novo item.

Ex https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNAZNQnig3E

Answer (score 1):

**O broadcast serve pra muitas coisas, exemplo você quer disparar um push para todos os clientes ao mesmo tempo dentro da aplicação.**

Exemplo:Um painel de hospital precisa atualizar quais leitos estão disponiveis ou ocupados, o Broadcast pode atualizar todas as telas de acordo com a atualização feita.

Todas outras respostas estão na documentação.

**https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting**